# Verify that a Weak-neighborhood of a point is contained in the kernel of a continuous linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I've encountered several times this reasoning but i can't find a good answer to it.

Let $ E, F$ be banach spaces

Given $\varphi : E \to F $ linear and continuous w.r.t the weak topology $\sigma (E, E^*) $ and the  strong topology in F. 
Then for every $\varepsilon > 0 $ there exists a neighborhood V of 0 in E s.t. $ x \in V \Rightarrow \| \varphi(x) \| < \varepsilon $. We may assume that V has the form $$ V  = \lbrace x \in E \mid \| \langle f_i , x \rangle \| < \delta \ \forall i = 1, 2, \dots , n \rbrace $$
Where $f_i \in E^* \forall i $

Let $M =  \lbrace x \in E \mid \langle f_i , x \rangle = 0 \forall i =1, 2,\dots n \rbrace $ so that (according to every book I've read) $$ \varphi (x)=0 \ \forall x \in M $$.

How can I verify that $ M \subseteq \text{ Ker }\varphi $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x \in M$, then $\langle f_i,x\rangle = 0$ for all $i$, hence $t\cdot x \in V$ for all $t\in \mathbb{K}$. That means

$$\lVert \varphi(t\cdot x)\rVert = \lVert t\cdot\varphi(x)\rVert = \lvert t\rvert\cdot \lVert \varphi(x)\rVert \leqslant \varepsilon$$

for all $t\in\mathbb{K}$. If $\varphi(y) \neq 0$, choose $$t = \frac{\varepsilon+1}{\lVert\varphi(y)\rVert}$$

to see $y \notin M$.

Comment: It was so simple? :) I've struggled myself using some kind of epsilon-delta arguments, or thinking about shrinking V as epsilon goes to 0. Anyway thanks! Perfect answer!

Comment: It becomes so simple after a couple of years working with topological vector spaces. It doesn't start simple.